# Not able to get get output

Tags: plsql, oracle11g

```
declare
num number(5);
rev number(5);
temp number(5);
begin 
num:=&num;
while num>0
loop
temp:=mod(num,10);
rev:=(rev*10)+temp;
num:=trunc(num/10);
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line('reversed no:' || rev);
end;
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
 Enter value for num: 456
 old   6: num:=&num;
 new   6: num:=456;
 reversed no:

    PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

if have used `set serveroutput on;`
i am using oracle 11g.
i tried every thing i can think of still having this problem.

Comment: Once you've understood the answer you may also look at other methods to do reverse( as string) in oracle : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35314500/how-to-reverse-a-string-in-oracle-11g-sql-without-using-reverse-function

Comment: Try the answer of @boneist. That surely will solve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lies in the line:

```
rev := (rev * 10) + temp;
```

At the point that line is called, rev is null. When you apply mathematical operators to a null value in Oracle, the result is always null.

You can get around this by assigning a value when you declare the variable, i.e.:

```
DECLARE
  num  NUMBER(5);
  rev  NUMBER(5) := 0;
  temp NUMBER(5);
BEGIN
  num := &num;
  WHILE num > 0
  LOOP
    temp := MOD(num, 10);
    rev  := (rev * 10) + temp;
    num  := trunc(num / 10);
  END LOOP;
  dbms_output.put_line('reversed no: ' || rev);
END;
/

reversed no: 654
```